# How do I prevent the HTML markup in an item list from being escaped?

Tags: theming

As you can see in the code below, I try various ways to prevent Drupal from escaping the HTML and passing the link tags to the output, including the use of '#allowed_tags' and the `Markup` class.  None of these approaches are working.

```
$text = t('Administer books');

$markup = new Markup();
$link = $markup->create(Link::fromTextAndUrl($text, $url)->toString());

$items[] = $link . ': ' . t('Browse books and edit fields') . '.';

$text = t('Import books');
$url = new Url('mei_marc.import');

$items[] = Link::fromTextAndUrl($text, $url)->toString() . ': ' . t('Visit this page to import a book') . '.';

$array['mei_marc_list'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#list_type' => 'ul',
  '#title' => '',
  '#items' => $items,
  '#allowed_tags' => ['a'],
);

$txt = drupal_render($array);

$markup = new Markup();

$list = $markup->create($txt);

return ['#markup' => $list];
```

The output is the following.

```
<div class="item-list">
<ul><li>&lt;a href=&quot;/mei_marc/list&quot;&gt;Administer books&lt;/a&gt;: Browse books and edit fields.</li>
<li>&lt;a href=&quot;/admin/mei_library/import&quot;&gt;Import books&lt;/a&gt;: Visit this page to import a book.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items[] = [
  '#markup' => Link::fromTextAndUrl($text, $url)->toString() . ': ' . t('Visit this page to import a book') . '.',
];

$form['mei_marc_list'] = [
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $items,
];

return $form;
```

Comment: Wow.  I didn't see that approach anywhere in my searches, and it works.